# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[String]

Tags: angular, angular7

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[String]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[String]:      NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
```

I faced the above issue when compiling my angular 7 project. below solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

(got this answer from github).
Add the below line in your app.module.ts in 'providers' array.
It solved the issue for me.

```
 providers: [
    {provide: String, useValue: "dummy"}
]
```

Comment: Yah... but this is a place for people asking questions. But you seem to already got it...?